# How do i email data from a form built with a while loop?

Tags: php, email, while-loop

As part of a project I have a form in which our clients can edit a list of the keywords in which we work on as part of their SEO.

This is the code I use to display the keywords we have for them on our database

```
<?php
$c = true;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $counter++;
  echo "<div" .(($c = !$c)?' class="right"':'') . ">";
  echo "<label for='keyword". $counter ."'>",
       "<strong>Keyword " . $counter . " </strong></label>";
  echo "<input type='text' name='keyword". $counter .
       "' id='keyword". $counter ."' value='". $row['keyword'] . "' />";
  echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

What I don't know what do do is collect the data when the form is submitted into an email. 
I have the PHP mail bit ready but struggling on this a bit.

Any help?

Comment: Wouldn't the same loop work?  Just change the `inputs` to `paragraphs` or `spans`.  Instead of echoing, concat the values into a variable to be used in the `message` parameter of the `mail` function.

Comment: I tried that but because I want the data the client has submitted the while loop wont work. it doesn't return anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend changing the code to this:

```
<?php
$c = true;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $counter++;
  echo "<div" .(($c = !$c)?' class="right"':'') . ">";
  echo "<label for='keyword". $counter ."'>",
       "<strong>Keyword " . $counter . " </strong></label>";
  echo "<input type='text' name='keyword[]' id='keyword". $counter ."' value='". $row['keyword'] . "' />";
  echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

You can then access all keywords in the target php file for your form (after submission) using `$_POST['keyword']`, eg

```
foreach($_POST['keyword'] as $key => $value) {
      echo "Keyword #". $key." value: ". $value."<br />";
      // or your code to build your message
}
```

Comment: hey, i tried this, didn't seem to do anything other than break my page :S

Comment: Apologies I'd accidentally ommited a semicolon from the final line of code, it should work now

Answer (score 0):

Instead of naming the inputs like "keyword1", "keyword2", etc, just name them all "keyword[]".  When the form is submitted, PHP will aggregate them all into an array.

Comment: PHP already aggregates them into the `$_POST` array because his names are all unique.

Comment: its actually better to assign them to a dedicated subarray as they are related datapoints +1

Comment: @Stephen, that's true, but aggregating them into a separate array makes iteration easier.  See Ergo Summary's answer.

Answer (score 0):

To use the POST data (make sure your form is using POST):

```
<?php
    $message = '<ol>';
    foreach($_POST as $key => $post) {
        $message .= "<li><strong>Keyword " . $key . ":</strong>";
        $message .= " <span>" . $post . "</span>";
        $message .= "</li>";
    }
    $message .= '</ol>';

    // mail the message here.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Brian and Ergo summary are right, but if you don't want to modify the code inside the while loop you could, at the end of that, insert an hidden input that holds the last $counter value. Then in the target php file (where you will send the email), you can load the POST fields (modifying what Stephen wrote):

```
<?php
$counter = (int)$_POST['counter'];
$message = '';
for($i = 1; $i <= $counter; $i++){
    $key = $_POST['keyword'.$i];
    $message .= "<p>";
    $message .= "<strong>Keyword " . $key . " </strong></label>";
    $message .= "<span> " . $post . "</span>";
    $message .= "</p>";
}

// mail message here.
?>
```